# Не работает qmake

Tags: qt5, qmake

Имеется файл qt-hello.cpp:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel lbl("Hello, World!");
    lbl.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

и pro-файл Hello.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT       += widgets
SOURCES  = qt-hello.cpp
windows:TARGET   = ../Hello
```

после `qmake -project -> qmake -> make` вылазит ошибка:

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I/opt/qt510/include -I/opt/qt510/include/QtGui -I/opt/qt510/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I/opt/qt510/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o qt-hello.o qt-hello.cpp
qt-hello.cpp:1:21: fatal error: QtWidgets: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:656: recipe for target 'qt-hello.o' failed
make: *** [qt-hello.o] Error 1
```

При этом если собираю с помощью `cmake`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)
project(hello)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
add_definitions(-Wall -std=c++14)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
set(SRC_MAIN qt-hello.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_MAIN})
qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Widgets)
```

то все собирается норм. В чем проблема? Что я сделал не так в pro-file?

Comment: Новый Qt на Linux, да?

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский qt 5.10.1 - вы это спрашивали?

Comment: @Andrej_Levkovitch, в смысле оська какая стоит?

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский прошу прощения но мне не знакома такая терминология: я только-только начинаю осваивать qt...

Comment: Операционная система какая? =)

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский а, это: линукс минт

Comment: Попробуйте в терминале `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский нет, уже установлен) Это я в первую очередь проверил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем проблема возникла из-за того, что я не разобрался в предназначении `qmake -project`... Оказалось (я этого еще вчера не знал), что это команда автоматически создает .pro файл в котором, конечно `widgets` не включен, а после команды `qmake` утилита создает `Makefile` основанный на автоматически созданном pro-файле. Вообщем не нужна сдесь команда `qmake -project`.